# How to rsync file pattern in subfolders

Tags: linux, bash, rsync

I have the following remote folder/file structure:

```
/home/user/backup/siteA/regionA/data.sql
/home/user/backup/siteA/regionA/data.clean.sql
/home/user/backup/siteA/regionA/data.lite.sql
/home/user/backup/siteA/regionA/files/
/home/user/backup/siteA/regionB/data.sql
/home/user/backup/siteA/regionB/data.clean.sql
/home/user/backup/siteA/regionB/data.lite.sql
/home/user/backup/siteA/regionB/files/
/home/user/backup/siteA/regionC/data.sql
/home/user/backup/siteA/regionC/data.clean.sql
/home/user/backup/siteA/regionC/data.lite.sql
/home/user/backup/siteA/regionC/files/
/home/user/backup/siteA/regionD/data.sql
/home/user/backup/siteA/regionD/data.clean.sql
/home/user/backup/siteA/regionD/data.lite.sql
/home/user/backup/siteA/regionD/files/
/home/user/backup/siteB/regionA/data.sql
/home/user/backup/siteB/regionA/data.clean.sql
/home/user/backup/siteB/regionA/data.lite.sql
/home/user/backup/siteB/regionA/files/
/home/user/backup/siteB/regionB/data.sql
/home/user/backup/siteB/regionB/data.clean.sql
/home/user/backup/siteB/regionB/data.lite.sql
/home/user/backup/siteB/regionB/files/
/home/user/backup/a-script.sh
/home/user/backup/backup.log
/home/user/backup/siteC
...
...
```

I need to rsync `*.clean.sql` and `*.lite.sql` from siteA to a similar structure locally, eg:

```
/var/data/dbs/siteA/regionA/data.clean.sql
/var/data/dbs/siteA/regionA/data.lite.sql
```

I cant seem to get `rsyn`c to include/exclude the right things. I am trying:

```
/usr/bin/rsync --archive --del --verbose --verbose --compress --progress --exclude-from=excludes.txt --rsh='ssh -q' --dry-run user@remote:/home/user/backup/siteA /var/data/dbs/siteA
```

And my excludes.txt contains:

```
+ *.clean.sql
+ *.lite.sql
- *
```

However I just get:

```
receiving incremental file list
[sender] hiding directory siteA because of pattern *
```

I have a script which can do this on a per-site-region basis, but not as a "whole". I've tried adding stars and slashes to the excludes list, but cant seem to find the right combo. Any suggestions?

### Update

I've got better results with

```
/usr/bin/rsync --archive --del --compress --progress --exclude-from=excludes.txt --rsh='ssh -q' user@remote:/home/user/backup/siteA /var/data/dbs/siteA
```

with the excludes.txt

```
+ */
+ *.clean.sql
+ *.lite.sql
- *
```

However, that also parses the contents of all the files folders (albeit to skip/exclude them) which slows it down a lot (and pollutes the rsync output with a huge directory listing).

Is there a "maxdepth" parameter?!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
cd /home/user/backup
find site* -name data.clean.sql -o -name data.lite.sql > filestobackup
rsync --archive --verbose --del --compress --progress \
--files-from=filestobackup -d \
--rsh='ssh -q' \
user@remote:/home/user/backup/ /var/data/dbs/
```

Comment: That wont work - that will rsync everything except the files I want :)

Comment: I want to rsync JUST `*.(clean|lite).sql` and ignore the rest, maintaining folder structure.

Comment: Thanks Stephane, however your suggesting is basically to use find to generate a list of files to sync and then set RSync to do that list. Although that would work, it makes this a two-step process... Doesn't feel "clean".

However I can see that using the "files-from" parameter would produce a fast rsync time as rsync wouldn't need to scan the system.